# Filtering an array of objects

Tags: javascript

The code does the following:

1. Gets an array of objects and filters them according to some properties
2. Returns the array of objects with the filtered data

I'm using the following code which is **working** and I wonder if there is a way to write it better.

By the way, I can use LodashJS if it's helpful here.

```
filterNullUndefinedOrRejected: function(oData) {
    if (oData && oData.length > 0) {
        var aNewExtendedObjects = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < oData.length; i++) {
            if (oData[i].va === null || oData[i].val === undefined || oData[i].state === "rejected") { 
                if (oData[i].state === "rejected") {
                      console.log(oData[i].error);
                }        
                oData.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
            else{
                aNewExtendedObjects.push(oData[i].val);
            }
        }
        return aNewExtendedObjects[0];  
    }
    return oData;   
},
```

Comment: I don't understand the line "return aNewExtendedObjects[0];" That returns just the first element of the results-array. Shouldn't it be "return aNewExtendedObjects;" ? So that the whole array is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`splice` mutates the existing array. You wouldn't want to do that as you might not be sure where else the array is being used. You might be expecting values in the array after calling this function, yet this function wiped them off.

Now if you're really sure you want to use `splice` to remove items in an array, loop backwards. The ending `i--` isn't very visible and missing it would mean skipped items.

Lodash isn't necessary as you have the native `array.filter`. This is unless you still plan to support browsers that don't do ES5 (like IE8 and older).

Your function isn't consistent. The ideal return is an array. But if I put in a falsy value, it returns that value, not an array.

The length check is meaningless. An empty array has the length of `0` which means the loop will never run at all.

Your function is essentially just including all values that aren't `null`, `undefined` or have a state of `rejected`. However, the name is misleading. You never explicitly mention that you're only getting the `val` properties as a result. You should name your function explicitly, or split off the operations separately.

As noted in the comments (and it wasn't apparent in the code), you're collecting the `val` property of the filtered items. This can easily be done with an `array.map`. So after filtering down to the items we do need, we transform the values to the ones we need.

```
filterNullUndefinedOrRejected: function(oData){
  return !oData ? [] : oData.filter(function(oDatum){
    if(oDatum.state === 'rejected') console.log(oDatum.error);
    return oDatum.val !== null && oDatum.val !== undefined && oDatum.state !== "rejected";
  }).map(function(oData){
    return oData.val;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you :-) , it seems that the code is not working  i've two questions 1. how can I change the code that I will be able to debug it easily 2. in the input array of object I've many objcts that I need to filter and in some case need to return array of filterd object, does your code is handle it?

Comment: I think I found the issue, the "wrong object" doesnt have the oDatum.val and the "right" object have  oDatum[0].val which I should return , so if I call to the function like this var aa = filtevar rNullUndefinedOrRejected(oData)  and return to the next function aa[0].val this is working but there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: @NinaS 1) Consider using dev tools, adding breakpoints, trace through code and watch scope variables. 2) `filter` returns an array.

Comment: Yep do it already please see my last comment I found the issue , see if you can help how to avoid the return aa[0].val , thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks it worked with map with  just a little modification in map return oData.val[0]

Comment: Something puzzles me. Your solution using `filter()` is obviously better than the OP's one, but I'm surprised you begin stating that "splice mutates the existing array. You wouldn't want to do that... etc". Am I wrong when I think it doesn't matter here because the `oData` argument, being an array, is passed by value, so only the local copy is affected? TIA for enlighting me!

Comment: @cFreed When JS passes primitives, the local variable gets a copy of the value. When JS passes non-primitives, the local variable will *point to the same exact value*. This means passing `foo` array to the function, `oData` points to the same array. JS is always passing by value. It's just a matter of are you getting a copy or pointing to the same thing.

Comment: "It's just a matter of are you getting a copy or pointing to the same thing": I totally agree, and this is for me _the_ important fact. But "JS is always passing by value" made me quite desorientated! So I did a small tour and I learned that the "by value" and "by reference" terms became confusing, because they seem to have lost the strict sense I knew from my original "culture" (where they were the exact equivalent of copy/pointer). Adding that I was thoughtlessly regarding array as primitive, it ends that I'm coding wrong about that for more than 10 years! Thanks a lot for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array filter method.

```
filterNullUndefinedOrRejected: function(oData) {
    if (oData && oData.length > 0) {
        return oData.filter(function(item){
            // this function is used on on each value in the array
            // if `false` is returned, that item is removed
            if (item.val === null || item.val === undefined || item.state === "rejected") { 
                if (item.state === "rejected") {
                      console.log(item.error);
                }
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use the lodash `_.filter`, the only slight difference is in syntax:

```
filterNullUndefinedOrRejected: function(oData) {
    if (oData && oData.length > 0) {
        return _.filter(oData, function(item){
            if (item.val === null || item.val === undefined || item.state === "rejected") { 
                if (item.state === "rejected") {
                      console.log(item.error);
                }
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        });
    }
}
```

Filter methods take an array and invokes a callback function on each item, expecting a boolean back. If false is returned, the item is removed.

This method returns a *new* array. So to update the data you would have to do something like:

```
dataSet = filterNullUndefinedOrRejected(dataSet);
```

[repl demo](https://repl.it/CGJD)

Comment: Thanks but it seems that your code is returning true or false, I need to take array of object filter it according the condition I put and return new array of multiple filtered objects...

Comment: The `true` and `false` you're referring to is in the callback function used by the `filter` method. That callback is used on each item in the array and removes the item if false is returned. Check it out [here (repl)](https://repl.it/CGJD)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested, there is an ES6 version of Joseph's response :

```
function filterNullUndefinedOrRejected (datas){
    return (!datas) ? [] : datas.filter(data => {
        if(data.state === 'rejected') console.log(data.error);
        return hasRejectedStateWithAValue(data);
    }).map(data => data.val);
}

function hasRejectedStateWithAValue(data) {
    return data.val !== null && data.val !== undefined && data.state !== "rejected";
}
```

Also I have extracted the condition expression in its own function to make the code more readable (the function name allow us to explain the goal of the condition).